# Insert titlerule underneath table of contents heading

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, tocloft

I have a line drawn under my chapter headings using `\titlerule[2pt]`. I want to achieve this same design underneath my 'Contents', 'List of Figures' and 'List of Tables' headings. Can anyone advise me how to do this?

[image]

I want that line also under the big 'Contents' heading. And the 'List of Figures' and 'List of Tables' headings on the other pages.
[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{newtxtext} 
\usepackage[a4paper, top=30mm,bottom=30mm,inner=25mm,outer=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.36}

\usepackage{tocbibind}

\usepackage{tocloft} 
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont} 
              {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge}
 \renewcommand{\cftchapfont} 
              {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}
 \renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont} 
             {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} 
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont} 
             {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{15pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{0.8ex}{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\allsectionsfont{\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont}

\makeatletter % Removes the word 'Chapter'
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Example section}
\subsection{Example subsection}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use option `titles` for package `tocloft`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{newtxtext} 
\usepackage[a4paper, top=30mm,bottom=30mm,inner=25mm,outer=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.36}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}% load after the other packages

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}
              {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{15pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{0.8ex}{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\allsectionsfont{\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont}

\makeatletter % Removes the word 'Chapter'
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Example section}
\subsection{Example subsection}
\end{document}
```

Note that the redefinitions of `\cfttoctitlefont`, `\cftloftitlefont` and `\cftlottitlefont`. Additionally there is no need for the `\cleardoublepage` commands before LoF and LoT.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\vspace{0.8ex}\endgraf\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\vspace{0.8ex}\endgraf\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\vspace{0.8ex}\endgraf\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}
```

Comment: Hmm... That didn't do anything?

Comment: @Milo: It's an interaction between `tocloft` and `titlesec`. But tocloft has the tools for what you want:. Please see the three lines I suggest. Other possibility: ake all the formatting with `titlesec` and its companion `titletoc`.